# Showing a set is a subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a group $G=S_4$. Let H={1, (123) ,(321), (12), (13), (23)}. Show that H is a subgroup of G.

What is the best way to do this.

I realised <(123)>={1, (123), (321)} but I don't think this helps much.

I do not want to compute every element * every other element to show closure.

Answer (score 1):

Just note no element moves 4, and that the permutations of 1,2,3 form a group of order 6. On the list there are 6 elements which don't move 4, so done.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? Permutation of 1,2,3 form....

Comment: I think what coffeemath means to say is that those elements of $S_{4}$ which fix the point $4$ form a subgroup, which has order $6$. All the elements you list fix $4$, so your set of size $6$ must be that subgroup.

Comment: Why is it a subgroup though? I understand it fixes 4 and is of order 6.

Comment: A permutation is a rearrangement. If it is of 1,2,3 then it can be 123,132,213,231,312,321. Each of these is on your list, e.g. your 1 is the identity 123 (no change of order) and (13) switches 1,3 and leaves anything else unmoved, here since in $S_4$ it leaves 2 alone so it is (as only for 1,2,3) the rearrangement 321. I assumed you knew that notation since it is in the question. Anyway, as a rearrangement of 1234 for example, (123) moves 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and 3 back to 1, so in list form it is 2314 as in $S_4,$ or as just in $S_3$ (which is your $H$) it is the rearrangement 231 of 123.

Comment: Lin: It is a subgroup because it contains *all* the rearrangements of 1,2,3, otherwise denoted $S_3.$

Comment: Lin-- Youi're welcome. These permutation groups can be fun, once one gets the notation down.

Comment: Can I say the elements of H fix 4 and H contains all the permutations of (1,2,3) i.e S3 which is a group, so H is a subgroup of G for full marks on an exam?

Comment: Also is there a shortcut to find the index of H in G?

Comment: Lin-- index of $H$ in $G$ is order of $G$ divided by order of $H.$ If you look up Lagrange's Theorem you can see why.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a set and let $Y \subseteq X$.

Let $G=S(X)$, the group of permutations of $X$, and $H$ be the set of permutations of $X$ that fix $Y$, in the sense that $\phi(Y) \subseteq Y$.

Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ as can be easily checked; $H$ is actually isomorphic to $S(X\setminus Y)$.

In your case, $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $Y=\{4\}$.

Your $H$ is simply $S_3 \subseteq S_4$.