# Subgroup of order $6$ in $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find a subgroup of order $6$ in $S_5$.

I know that it would be $S_3$ is proper subset of $S_5$ as $3!=6$. I do not understand how to make a subgroup of order $6$ in $S_5$. $$\{(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(2,4,5), (1,4,5),(2,3,4),(1,2,4),(1,2,5), \text{and so on}\}$$ 
Is this right way to write it? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is the question "find a subgroup of order $6$" or "find all subgroups of order $6$"?

Comment: find a subgroup of order 6

Comment: Okay, but then you've answered your own question, right? The description you gave of $S_3$ is a subgroup of $S_5$. It may be helpful to also say that this is the subgroup which leave the numbers $4$ and $5$ fixed.

Comment: (Also, I find it frustrating that a new user here receives 2 down votes within 4 minutes of asking their first question, and 2 close votes within 6 minutes. The downvotes were before my first comment. Be nice, people!)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639128/589

Comment: ok. and what about example of minimal generating set in case of S5?

Comment: @User, ask one question at a time

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question, as it is really just a "check my answer" question, which is fine. The only issue is the second, disjoint question, which I've deleted and which the OP should ask separately.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two groups of order $6$: $S_3$ and $C_6$. $S_5$ has several copies of both:

- Choose two elements $a,b$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The permutations that fix $a,b$ form a subgroup of $S_5$ that is isomorphic to $S_3$.
- Take a 3-cycle $\sigma$ and a 2-cycle $\tau$ disjoint from $\sigma$. Then $\sigma\tau$ has order $6$ and so generate a subgroup of $S_5$ that is isomorphic to $C_6$.

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me what about example of minimal generating set in case of S5?